# Problema no carregamento de imagem

Tags: javascript, html, php-5

Esse é o problema que da galera se alguem poder ajudar ficarei grato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Aqui está o codigo do HTML...**

aqui é a parte onde carregará a imagem com o produto que será adicionado.

```
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="box-all">                               
                            <!--{loop:i}-->
                            <!--{<div class="span2">}-->
                            <!--{  <a href="[baseUri]/produto/i.categoria_url/i.sub_url/i.item_url/i.item_id/">}-->
                            <!--{     <div class="box-item tips-top" title="ver detalhes">}-->
                            <!--{        <div class="box-item-oferta-i.item_oferta"><span class="label label-important">Oferta</span></div>}-->
                            <!--{        <div class="box-item-foto"><img src="thumber.php?q=70&zc=2&w=160&h=160&src=fotos/i.foto_url" width="160" height="160" /></div>}-->
                            <!--{        <div class="box-item-detalhe">}-->
                            <!--{          <h2>i.item_short_title</h2>}-->
                            <!--{          <h4 class="i.showHide">De R$ i.item_valor_original</h4>}-->
                            <!--{          <h3>i.item_preco <br/> <small>i.item_valor_parc</small></h3>}-->
                            <!--{        </div>}-->                            
                            <!--{     </div>}-->
                            <!--{  </a>}-->
                            <!--{</div>}-->
                            <!--{end:i}-->
                        </div>
```

**E aqui está o codigo do PHP...**

aqui é onde fica o caminho das imagens.

```
    <?php

class Thumb extends PHPFrodo
{

    public function welcome()
    {
        if ( isset( $this->uri_segment[1] ) )
        {
            $pic = "app/fotos/" . $this->uri_segment[1] . ".jpg";
            if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
            {
                $pic = "app/fotos/" . $this->uri_segment[1] . ".png";
                if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
                {
                    $pic = "app/images/default/nopic.jpg";
                }
            }
            $this->helper( 'canvas' );
            $t = new Canvas;
            $t->carrega( $pic );
            $image_x = $this->uri_segment[2];
            $image_y = $this->uri_segment[3];
            if ( isset( $this->uri_segment[4] ) && $this->uri_segment[4] == 'ratio' )
            {
                $t->redimensiona( $image_x, $image_y, 'crop' );
            }
            else
            {
                $t->redimensiona( $image_x, $image_y );
            }
            $t->grava( null, 85 );
        }
    }

    public function slide()
    {
        if ( isset( $this->uri_segment[2] ) )
        {
            $pic = "app/fotos/slide/" . $this->uri_segment[2] . ".jpg";
            if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
            {
                $pic = "app/fotos/slide/" . $this->uri_segment[2] . ".png";
                if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
                {
                    $pic = "app/images/default/nopic.jpg";
                }
            }
            $this->helper( 'canvas' );
            $t = new Canvas;
            $t->carrega( $pic );
            if ( isset( $this->uri_segment[3] ) )
            {
                $image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
                $image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
                if ( isset( $this->uri_segment[5] ) && $this->uri_segment[5] == 'crop' )
                {
                    $t->redimensiona( $image_x, $image_y, 'crop' );
                }
                else
                {
                    $t->redimensiona( $image_x, $image_y );
                }
            }
            $t->grava( null, 85 );
            //$t->grava();
        }
    }

    public function slider()
    {
        $pic = "app/fotos/slide/" . $this->uri_segment[2] . ".jpg";
        if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
        {
            $pic = "app/fotos/slide/" . $this->uri_segment[2] . ".png";
            if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
            {
                $pic = "app/images/default/nopic.jpg";
            }
        }
        $handle = new upload( $pic );
        $handle->image_resize = true;
        if ( isset( $this->uri_segment[5] ) && $this->uri_segment[5] == 'crop' )
        {
            $handle->image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
            $handle->image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
            $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
        }
        elseif ( isset( $this->uri_segment[5] ) && $this->uri_segment[5] == 'ratio' )
        {
            $handle->image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
            $handle->image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
            $handle->image_ratio_y = true;
            //$handle->image_ratio_x = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $handle->image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
            $handle->image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
        }
        $handle->png_compression = 9;
        $handle->jpeg_quality = 85;
        @header( 'Content-type: ' . $handle->file_src_mime );
        echo $handle->Process();
        die();
    }

    public function thumbr()
    {
        $pic = "app/fotos/" . $this->uri_segment[2] . ".jpg";
        if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
        {
            $pic = "app/fotos/" . $this->uri_segment[2] . ".png";
            if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
            {
                $pic = "app/images/default/nopic.jpg";
            }
        }
        $handle = new upload( $pic );
        $handle->image_resize = true;
        if ( isset( $this->uri_segment[5] ) && $this->uri_segment[5] == 'crop' )
        {
            $handle->image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
            $handle->image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
            $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
        }
        elseif ( isset( $this->uri_segment[5] ) && $this->uri_segment[5] == 'ratio' )
        {
            $handle->image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
            $handle->image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
            //$handle->image_ratio_y = true;
            $handle->image_ratio_x = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $handle->image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
            $handle->image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
        }
        $handle->jpeg_quality = 85;
        @header( 'Content-type: ' . $handle->file_src_mime );
        echo $handle->Process();
        die();
    }

    public function t()
    {
        $pic = "app/fotos/" . $this->uri_segment[2] . ".jpg";
        if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
        {
            $pic = "app/fotos/" . $this->uri_segment[2] . ".png";
            if ( !file_exists( $pic ) )
            {
                $pic = "app/images/default/nopic.jpg";
            }
        }
        if ( empty( $this->uri_segment[2] ) )
        {
            $pic = "app/images/default/nopic.jpg";
        }
        $handle = new upload( $pic );
        $handle->image_resize = true;
        if ( isset( $this->uri_segment[5] ) && $this->uri_segment[5] == 'crop' )
        {
            $handle->image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
            $handle->image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
            $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
        }
        elseif ( isset( $this->uri_segment[5] ) && $this->uri_segment[5] == 'ratio' )
        {
            $handle->image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
            $handle->image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
            //$handle->image_ratio_x = true;
            $handle->image_ratio_y = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $handle->image_x = $this->uri_segment[3];
            $handle->image_y = $this->uri_segment[4];
        }
        $handle->jpeg_quality = 90;
        @header( 'Content-type: ' . $handle->file_src_mime );
        echo $handle->Process();
        die();
    }
}
/*end file*/
```

Detalhe **Importante** dentro do painel de administrador a imagem aparece normalmente mais quando entra no site ela não aparece e quando clica no produto da o problema acima...

Aqui o código onde carrega os novos produtos adicionados...

```
    var baseUri = $('base').attr('href').replace('/app/', '');
$(function () {
    //$(window).load(function () {
        //carrega novos produtos (ultimos cadastrados)
        var url = baseUri + '/index/FillMaisNovosVistos/2/';
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            $('#mais-novos .slides').html('');
            $(data).each(function (k, v) {
                var link = ''
                link += '<div class="span2">';
                link += ' <div class="box-item tips-top" title="ver detalhes">';

                link += '   <a href="' + baseUri + '/produto/' + v.categoria_url + '/' + v.sub_url + '/' + v.item_url + '/' + v.item_id + '/">';

                link += '     <div class="box-item-foto">'
                link += '       <img src="' + baseUri + '/app/thumber.php?q=80&zc=2&w=140&h=140&src=fotos/' + v.foto_url + '" style="width:140px !important" width="140" height="140"  class="img-responsive"/>';
                link += '     </div>'

                link += '     <div class="box-item-detalhe">'
                link += '      <h2>' + v.item_short_title + '</h2>'
                                if (v.item_valor_original) {
                                link += '<h4>De R$ ' + v.item_valor_original + '</h4>';
                                }                
                link += '      <h3>' + v.item_preco + '</h3>'
                link += '     </div>'

                link += '</a>'
                link += '</div>';
                link += '</div>';

                $('<li />')
                        .attr('id', v.item_id)
                        .html(link)
                        .appendTo($('#mais-novos .slides'));
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que seja pelo que o src procura um caminho, coloque todo o conteudo que solicita a imagem em uma função aonde o return é o caminho completo.

tipo assim

```
function linkimg(){

 url = thumber.php?q=70&zc=2&w=160&h=160&src=fotos/i.foto_url;
 return url;

}
```

algo com `ajax` para poder retornar um `obj` ou `json` para facilitar.